# Ableton 11 not installing with wine

Tags: wine

When I open the installer for Ableton 11 with wine, the installer gets an error about a minute after it opens. Any fixes?

Logs:

```
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Initializing version variable 'VCRedistToInstall' to value '14.27.29016.0'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i009: Command Line: '"-burn.clean.room=Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\Ableton Live_11_Suite_Installer.exe" -burn.filehandle.attached=120 -burn.filehandle.self=124'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\Ableton Live_11_Suite_Installer.exe'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\users\marcus\Temp\Ableton_Live_11_Suite_20210412111259.log'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Ableton Live 11 Suite'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Ableton'
[00FC:010C][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[00FC:010C][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '11.0.0.0'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Product or related product not found: {36F68A90-239C-34DF-B58C-64B30153CE35}
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i000: Setting version variable 'InstalledVC20152019Redist' to value '0.0.0.0'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i052: Condition 'InstalledVC20152019Redist >= VCRedistToInstall' evaluates to false.
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]w120: Detected partially cached package: Setup.msi, invalid payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, reason: 0x80070002
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]w120: Detected partially cached package: Setup.msi, invalid payload: pay63E897D16B115CEA443ABC747207B6E3, reason: 0x80070002
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i101: Detected package: vcredist_x64.exe, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i101: Detected package: Setup.msi, state: Absent, cached: Partial
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:12:59]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[00FC:010C][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 0
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: vcredist_x64.exe
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcredist_x64.exe' to value 'C:\users\marcus\Temp\Ableton_Live_11_Suite_20210412111259_000_vcredist_x64.exe.log'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Setup.msi' to value 'C:\users\marcus\Temp\Ableton_Live_11_Suite_20210412111259_001_Setup.msi_rollback.log'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Setup.msi' to value 'C:\users\marcus\Temp\Ableton_Live_11_Suite_20210412111259_001_Setup.msi.log'
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i201: Planned package: vcredist_x64.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i201: Planned package: Setup.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i300: Apply begin
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i359: Paused automatic updates.
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\windows\Temp\{57E0A985-D401-46B7-8878-7B113AB8DBB8}\.be\Ableton Live 11 Suite Installer.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}\Ableton Live 11 Suite Installer.exe'
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}, version: 11.0.0.0
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i304: Verified existing payload: vcredist_x64.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\75F1AEE6DCCF3D6E6AC49926563737005B93BA13\vcredist_x64.exe.
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i304: Verified existing payload: Setup.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FB6EECE6-87D2-4538-A1CE-61CCCA7C3DCE}v11.0.0.0\Setup.msi.
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:01]i338: Acquiring package: Setup.msi, payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, copy from: Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\Ableton Live 11 Suite Installer Data 1.cab
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:13]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\'
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:15]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, expected: 800199F49C3C4803F03BC068F471346D5BB65700, actual: A98FBD90705380A7D02C2A84C07BB010116C2A83
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:15]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:15]e310: Failed to verify payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:15]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:15]e314: Failed to cache payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A from working path: C:\windows\Temp\{57E0A985-D401-46B7-8878-7B113AB8DBB8}\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, error: 0x80091007.
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:15]e349: Application requested retry of payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, encountered error: 0x80091007. Retrying...
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:18]i338: Acquiring package: Setup.msi, payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, copy from: Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\Ableton Live 11 Suite Installer Data 1.cab
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:31]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, expected: 800199F49C3C4803F03BC068F471346D5BB65700, actual: A98FBD90705380A7D02C2A84C07BB010116C2A83
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:31]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:31]e310: Failed to verify payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:32]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:32]e314: Failed to cache payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A from working path: C:\windows\Temp\{57E0A985-D401-46B7-8878-7B113AB8DBB8}\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, error: 0x80091007.
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:32]e349: Application requested retry of payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, encountered error: 0x80091007. Retrying...
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:35]i338: Acquiring package: Setup.msi, payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, copy from: Z:\home\marcus\files\Ableton.Live.Suite.11.v11.0.0.Incl.Patched.and.Keygen-R2R\Ableton Live 11 Suite Installer Data 1.cab
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, expected: 800199F49C3C4803F03BC068F471346D5BB65700, actual: A98FBD90705380A7D02C2A84C07BB010116C2A83
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:48]e310: Failed to verify payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[0110:0120][2021-04-12T11:13:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A
[00FC:0124][2021-04-12T11:13:48]e314: Failed to cache payload: pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A from working path: C:\windows\Temp\{57E0A985-D401-46B7-8878-7B113AB8DBB8}\pay1F74FBCDDD774F9BF92113EB94F00B9A, error: 0x80091007.
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:48]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:48]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:48]i352: Removing cached bundle: {92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}\
[0110:0114][2021-04-12T11:13:48]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{92d4040b-4cb4-4710-802b-a742c194a235}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[00FC:0100][2021-04-12T11:13:49]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80091007, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have Visual C++.

```
Setting version variable 'InstalledVC20152019Redist' to value '0.0.0.0'
```

This seems to find the current version of MSVC, which is 0, so I assume you don't have it:

```
Initializing version variable 'VCRedistToInstall' to value '14.27.29016.0'
```

and this seems to set the minimum needed version to run Ableton:

```
Condition 'InstalledVC20152019Redist >= VCRedistToInstall' evaluates to false.
```

this finds that you don't have the required version, and so it fails to install.